# Как сделать autocomplite?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

Я делаю поиск на сайте. Есть input в, который вводиться поисковая строка. Если я отпарвляю запрос на сервер при каждом клике клавиши,то результаты начинают мелькать и формируеться очень много запросов на сервер. Мне нужно чтобы запрос на сервер отправлялся только через 1с как человек закончит печатать. Я думаю что человек закончит печатать если значение поля не измениться в течении 1 секунды

Вот что осталось после часа попыток)

Либо можно сделать с помощью jquery ui , но при клике на кнопку клавиатуры должен отправиться запрос на сервер и показаться результат. Я посмотерл и в jquery autocomplite такого не заметил, он выбирает уже из какого-то набора данных((

```js
var input = $('input');


var begin=0;
var stop = new Date().getTime();

input.keyup(function(e){
   var value = this.value; 
  $('div').children('span').remove();
  console.log('----------------keyup----------');
console.log(begin);
  console.log(stop);
  console.log(value);
  

  
  if(value.length>=3){
    send();
  }
  
  function send(){
    if(begin===0){
      setTimeout(function(){
       console.log('--begin = 0--');
        send();
      },1000);
    }
    begin = new Date().getTime()-stop;//прошедшее время
    
    console.log(begin);
    
    if(begin<1000){
      console.log('надо ещё подождать');
      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('== callback ==');
        send();
      },1000-begin);
    }else{
      console.log('пора отсылать');
      $('div').append('<span>Text</span>');
      stop = new Date().getTime();
    }
  }
  
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text">
  <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял что требуется то нужно сделать функцию delay

```
var delay = (function(){
var currentTime = 0;
    return function(callback, ms){
       clearTimeout (currentTime);
       currentTime = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();    

$(input).keyup(function(){
    delay(function(){
        console.log('time over');
      }, 1000 );
})
```

Comment: Нужно чтобы результаты поиска(которые показываються с помощью функции) выводились только после 1с как человек закончил вводить данные в поле. Чтобы не было мельканий результатов.

Comment: ну вот с помощью такого delay, запрос (и все другие действия) будут осуществлены через пару секунд после того как перестали вводить что либо в инпут.

Comment: Ааа.. всё я понял)) Спасибо)